# Changing boot partition from logical to primary

Tags: boot, windows-8.1, mbr

So I previously booted to my Windows 8.1 from a logical partition. First I want to know how exactly is that possible. Does it hold MBR record on some other primary partition?

I have two disks: Samsung and Seagate.
My Windows is on Seagate disk, on C: D partition (which is now primary but before it was logical), and I can't boot from that partition, I can't even boot from that disk, I boot from Samsung disk eventhought I don't have an OS installed on it.
So why is that so? My guess is that, a D partition still holds its boot record on that Samsung disk on some partition, so it boots from there.

So how do I fix that so that it boots from Seagate disk from D partition? [Here's a picture of my MBR's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nb4kO.png).
Partition C: D is active, I have checked it.
I know C: D partition is marked as boot partition on a picture, but if I try to boot from that disk it fails.

And there is also one thing more that I think can also be a source of a problem. And that is, I had Linux installed on E partition; and when I installed it I had a problem that I could no more boot to Windows so I simply formated that partition and now when I try to boot from that disk it tries to boot Linux and it fails, end enters GRUB rescue. 
But even before installing Linux I also remember I needed to boot from Samsung disk to get to Windows.

Hope I was clear enough...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MBR Boot sequence for Windows 7/8/10:

1) MBR (first sector on disk) from first disk

2) boot sector (first sector on partition) from active partition on first disk

3) boot manager from active partition first disk (reads BCD file)

In BCD (Boot Configuration Data) there can be any primary or logical partition as base address for an OS like Windows 7/8/10.

Active partition can be only a primary partition (you cannot make a logical partition active).

OS can reside on primary or logical partition on any accessible disk.

**Note:** If first disk has no active partition then boot sequence is tried on next disk and so on.

Hope this explains your first question.

---

To make a disk bootable:

1) Write Windows MBR code using bootsect.exe

2) Write Windows boot sector code to active partition (if there is no active partition, make first primary partition active using Disk Management)

```
bootsect /nt60 N: /mbr
```

where N: is active partition. Command fulfills 1) and 2)

3) Use bcdboot.exe to write/update boot related files

```
bcdboot c:\windows /s N:
```

where c: maps to OS partition, N: is active partition

Change drive letters to reflect your mappings.

Comment: Thanks, it worked!

And, my question was: How can you boot to OS that is installed on a logical partition if you can only boot from primary partition? Does it hold its necessary data on some other primary partion?

Now I'm also wondering how does multiboot work, it actually enables you to boot from a partition that is not active, or it converts it quickly to active in boot time?

Comment: Boot files(and BCD) are on active partition. Boot Configuration Data (BCD) holds one boot entry per installed OS which can be on any partition. Think of Boot Manager and its configuration as a separate thing which knows how to boot an OS on any partition. Boot Manager and its data are always on active partition so BIOS can start it from there.